# How do I transfer data from a text box to a label in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, textbox, label, listener

I'm doing a project for school in which I need to transfer data from a text-box into label 'data'? how do i do so? this is my code, the work for this project was done over a previous lab for that class, so the codes under the listeners are not for this lab. I just need help with "EDlistener". I tried but get "java:89: error: unreachable statement", please keep in my mind while answering, that I'm only just a beginner. Thanks.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class panelFinal extends JPanel
{

private JLabel label2;
private JLabel labelData, labelMean,   LabelStan;  //field
private JTextField box; //field
private JCheckBox click;
private int dataNumber;
private String dataStr[] = new String [50];
private int data1[] = new int [50];
private int data2[] = new int [51];
private String dataString;




public panelFinal()
{
  setLayout (null);

  JButton EnterData = new JButton ("Enter Data");
  EnterData.addActionListener (new EDListener());
  EnterData.setBounds(10,10,100,40);
  add(EnterData);

  JButton Statistics = new JButton ("Statistics");
  Statistics.addActionListener (new SListener ());
  Statistics.setBounds(120,10,100,40);
  add(Statistics);

  JButton Graphdata = new JButton ("Graph data");
  Graphdata.addActionListener (new GListener ());
  Graphdata.setBounds(230,10,100,40);
  add(Graphdata);

  JButton quit = new JButton ("Quit");
  quit.addActionListener (new quitListener ());
  quit.setBounds(340,10,100,40);
  add(quit);

  box = new JTextField ("", 60);
  box.setHorizontalAlignment (SwingConstants.LEFT);
  box.setBounds(10,55,450,22);
  add(box);

  labelData = new JLabel ("Data:");
  labelData.setHorizontalAlignment (SwingConstants.LEFT);
  labelData.setForeground(Color.blue);
  labelData.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
  labelData.setBounds(10,80,200,20);
  add(labelData);

  labelMean = new JLabel ("Mean:");
  labelMean.setHorizontalAlignment (SwingConstants.LEFT);
  labelMean.setForeground(Color.blue);
  labelMean.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
  labelMean.setBounds(10,115,200,20);
  add(labelMean);

  LabelStan = new JLabel ("Standard Deviation:");
  LabelStan.setHorizontalAlignment (SwingConstants.LEFT);
  LabelStan.setForeground(Color.blue);
  LabelStan.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
  LabelStan.setBounds(10,145,200,20);
  add(LabelStan);








}
private class EDListener implements ActionListener
{
  public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
  {
     String test;
     test = box.getText();

     if ( test.equals("") ); 
     return;

    String dataString = "Data:";
     dataStr = box.getText().split("\\a");
     dataNumber = dataStr.length;


     for (int i=0; i<=dataNumber-1; i++)
     {
        data1[i] = Integer.parseInt(dataStr[i]);

        if (data1[i] < 50)
           data1[i] = 50;

        dataString =  dataString + dataStr[i];
        if (i != dataNumber-1)
           dataString = dataString + ", ";
     }
     labelData.setText(dataString);
     repaint();

  }
}
```

Comment: umm, has javascript changed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the getText() method on the textfield to get the text as a string, and setText(String) on the label to set it.

Comment: thank you for replying but like i said im a beginner, i dont know how you would do that, help?